# HBase EndPoint co-Processor

Tags: hbase

What I have read on HBase Co-Processor is that, Co-Processor code gets executed on a specific `region`. My Question is

- Does It allow `Put` operation which happens to go on another `region` because of `key`
- When Somebody does `scan` in the co-process does this `scan` happens only in the context of that `region` where the co-processor is called for

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it should execute the code on a per-region basis, I hope someone will complete the answer in comment with more detail